# Excel: Need a function to count if the given time interval exist within a specific time range...ignoring the given date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula to count if the person still signed in within a time frame. For example:

```
Person  TimeIn              TimeOut
1       6/22/2013 10:32 AM  6/22/2013 11:35 AM
2       6/22/2013 10:36 AM  6/22/2013 12:52 PM
3       6/23/2013 10:40 AM  6/23/2013 5:15 PM
4       6/25/2013 12:42 PM  6/25/2013 1:25 PM
5       6/25/2013 1:42 PM   6/25/2013 4:53 PM
6       6/26/2013 3:30 PM   6/26/2013 5:00 PM
```

`10:00AM - 12:00PM` The count should be `3`. Person 1 2 3 is signed in between those two time
`12:00PM - 2:00PM` The count should be `4`. Person 2 3 4 5 is signed in between those two time
`2:00PM - 4:00PM` The count should be `3`. Person 3 5 6 is signed in between those two time
`4:00PM - 6:00PM` The count should be `3`. Person 3 5 6 is signed in between those two time
Basically if the person have not signed out, and is between those two time, i need a count ignoring the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming TimeIn/TimeOut data in `B2:C7` then you can put a specific time range in `E2/F2`, e.g. 10:00 AM in `E2`, 12:00 PM in `F2` then use this formula in `G2` for a count of people present at any part of that period

`=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(B$2:B$7,1)<F2)*(MOD(C$2:C$7,1)>E2))`

See sample [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucgdywedmqjprnf/tiime%20ranges.xls)

`MOD` function extracts the time only from the date/time values

Note: this won't work with time periods passing midnight like `8:00 PM` one day to `5:00 AM` the next (although I could adapt it to do so)

Comment: Yes you are correct, 4:00 PM to 6:00 PM should have count 3, i fixed that error. 

I dont need the time period passing midnight. Its for the usage of a community computer lab and its open from 10am - 9pm so the ranges i need is:
10:00 AM - 12:00 PM,
12:00 PM - 2:00 PM,
2:00 PM - 4:00 PM,
4:00 PM - 6:00 PM,
6:00 PM - 9:00 PM
and the lab closes at 9 so everyone one should be signed out and those times are recorded so no one will past midnight.
i'm not at home right now but when i get home i'll check out that function.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I wanted... that satisfy one of my conditions. How can I add this along with other conditions... for example....(user type column) D2:D7 = "A" AND (date column) B2:B7 < 6/22/2013 12:00:00 AM AND B2:B7 > 6/25/2013 11:59:59 PM AND (the condition you gave me) so what I really need what u gave me along with more conditions.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Aren't those last conditions the wrong way round? should > and < be reversed? In any case you can keep adding conditions to SUMPRODUCT with *, e.g. just to add the "user type" condition it would be =SUMPRODUCT((MOD(B$2:B$7,1)<F2)*(MOD(C$2:C$7,1)>E2)`*(D$2:D$7="A")`) - keep adding conditions as required

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first 'Time In' record ('6/22/2013 10:32 AM') is in cell B2, use the following formula to tell you whether the time, despite the date, is either: 10-12, 12-2, 2-4, 4-6, or outside of those ranges, placing it in cell D2, filling it down.

```
=IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))>=0.41667,TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))<0.5),"10-12",IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))>=0.5,TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))<0.58333),"12-2",IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))>=0.58333,TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))<0.66667),"2-4",IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))>=0.66667,TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"hh:mm"))<0.74999),"4-6","Out of Specified Time Ranges"))))
```

Comment: A pivot table could or the CountIF formula could be used to get counts of each one.

Comment: Im not a excel expert but from what i can get from this formula is testing the TimeIn if its in the ranges and if it is, return the range in text. then use a countif to count those results for each row.

the problem is that... for example Person 3 lies in 3 ranges. but it only returns the FIRST range according to the if condition. i dont know if im fully understanding or missing something. thank you for helping me. much appreciated ;)

Comment: I agree Jimmy, see my solution.......

Comment: Nice work Barry; do you know a good resource for learning more about the sum product function?

Comment: Excel MVP Bob Phillips has an excellent SUMPRODUCT write-up - http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html